# Apply OpenVPN gateway to a single interface

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, linux-networking

I'd like to be able to use my VPN internet connection through `tun0` for specific tasks as needed through commands like:

```
curl --interface tun0 ipinfo.io/json
```

My VPN provider pushes a new default route to the client upon connection, this forces all machine traffic through the VPN, which I do not want.

I tried adding `route-nopull` to my OpenVPN client configuration, but that stopped the gateway from being configured on `tun0`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add routes to the networks you need with `route` command, and use your non-VPN router as the gateway for those networks.